# How would I access a struct variable from another function?

Tags: variables, struct, rust

I'm trying to make a simple game as practice learning Rust, and I want to create a function that prints the stats of the player.

I created a structure for the players stats, and then defined them in the main function.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Player<'a> {
    max_health: i32,
    current_health: i32,
    attack_dmg: i32,
    level: i32,
    name: &'a str,
}
```

And then defined them like this:

```
pub fn main() {
    let mut name = "";
    let mut level = 1;
    let mut attack_dmg = 30;
    const max_health: i32 = 100;
    let mut current_health = 100;
    let player = Player { name, level, attack_dmg, current_health, max_health };
}
```

I then print the stats like this:

```
pub fn stat_printer() {
    println!("Your stats are: {:?}", player);
}
```

When I try to compile I get the error that the player is not found in the scope of the stat printer function.

Comment: You seem to not be familiar with the idea of [scopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). Rust, like every compiled language I know of, introduces a new unique sope for each function. If you want to use your variables in other functions, consider passing them as [parameters](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-03-how-functions-work.html#function-parameters).

Comment: Yes, I'm not particularly familiar. I'm pretty new to programming in general. Thank you the links and info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your `stat_printer()` function, you do not have access to `player` which you have initialized in `main`. Try passing `player` as reference parameter to `stat_printer()`, but you have to make `Player` struct public as well.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Player<'a> {
    max_health: i32,
    current_health: i32,
    attack_dmg: i32,
    level: i32,
    name: &'a str,
}

// ...

pub fn stat_printer(player: &Player) {
    println!("Your stats are: {:?}", player);
}
```

Passing as reference (&Player) is necessary, so the function `stat_printer` does not take ownership of it, which makes passed parameter reusable.